# Assigning directly velocity vs AddForce()

Tags: unity-game-engine

You have tons of tutorials, and comments about applying velocity, simulate jump and they all are contradictory. For example, reading comments in "Better Jumping in Unity With Four Lines of Code" in youtube some say you should avoid assigning velocity directly.

That's what I'm trying to do, (= only use `AddForce()`) and they (the Unity team) have added another force mode, so here are the available options:

```
public enum ForceMode
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   <para>Add a continuous force to the rigidbody, using its mass.</para>
    /// </summary>
    Force = 0,
    /// <summary>
    ///   <para>Add an instant force impulse to the rigidbody, using its mass.</para>
    /// </summary>
    Impulse = 1,
    /// <summary>
    ///   <para>Add an instant velocity change to the rigidbody, ignoring its mass.</para>
    /// </summary>
    VelocityChange = 2,
    /// <summary>
    ///   <para>Add a continuous acceleration to the rigidbody, ignoring its mass.</para>
    /// </summary>
    Acceleration = 5,
}
```

What I'm asking is *not* opinion based, it's: when and when *not* assign directly velocity?

If I'm not wrong it seems that `VelocityChange` is a substitute of assigning directly velocity.

And yes I've [RTFM](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.VelocityChange.html) and I don't understand their sample (it uses `GUI.Button` which is officially considered obsolete...).

Comment: What is your question? (It usually ends in a `?`)

Comment: @Draco18s " when and when not assign directly velocity"???

Comment: I can only give opinions, and have thousands of them ;). However, what I'm about to say is even worse than an opinion, it's an observation. Nobody knows enough about using physics for gameplay creation to answer this question. Most everyone uses physics in only the ways they understand it, and don't ever experiment or otherwise explore and navigate its potential to be used (and abused) in other ways.

Comment: And there's NOTHING wrong with abusing a physics system to get whatever desired results you want, however you want, abusing it in any ways you can imagine, find or otherwise intuit. I really, really abuse it, and sometimes use it. And make a lot of experiments because there's almost nothing useful about anything to do with creatively using physics, largely because nobody has ever done the thinking and groundwork on how it can be fully abused and used, so there's no base thinking on what the really wide potential for these amazing systems are. And they are INCREDIBLY capable systems.

Comment: So, rather than thinking in rules and "best practices", rights and wrongs and all the other group think that goes with everything to do with anything in coding, I strongly suggest you can probably achieve whatever result you want, however you want, and wave a single, middle finger, to any and all rules about how to use physics systems. They're fun, reliable and rewarding. In the extreme. I think.

Comment: Sometimes you want objects with different masses to "feel" different to the player.  That's when you should use force.  Sometimes you don't care about mass and just want it to go a certain speed.  That's when you should use velocity.  People say to avoid velocity setting because its really hard to get spring constants, mass, friction constants, and other physics properties to look right when you have parts of the code ignoring the object's mass because they set velocity directly.

Comment: @Confused You could (copy all your comments) + (paste them into an answer). This shoud be enough for me. My other (hidden) question is: is it sustainable in the long run? (Even though long run is never more than 3 months with the Unity team (joke))

Comment: @LeoBartkus Very clever and smart answer. So you could answer here too **`;)`**. I dont know why people prefer to comment rather than answer.

Comment: I didn't really think of what I said as an answer. Although I will happily suggest abusing physics. I get the joke about Unity refreshes and inconsistencies. I do. I do, my oh my, I do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all down to how you want the game to feel. If you assign velocity directly, you get very tight control over how an object moves, whereas if you use forces, you can get more realistic movement based on the mass of the object.

For example: if you're making a very fast-paced game where twitch inputs are important, you should probably assign velocity directly.

Alternatively: if you were, for example, making a game where you roll a ball around and you wanted to have balls made from different materials with different masses, you'd probably want to use forces to make the movement believable.

Also, you're right about how using `AddForce` with `VelocityChange` is equivalent to assigning velocity directly.